# Usage of enum and char in switch statements

Tags: c++, enums

I have a piece of code with enum as a parameter in the switch statement and it works as expected.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef enum
{
    first=0, second=1, third, fourth, fifth, sixth
}enumValue;

void enumFunction(enumValue val)
{
    switch(val)
    {
    case first : std::cout<<"1\n";
                 break;

    case second : std::cout<<"2\n";
                  break;

    case fifth  : std::cout<<"5\n";
                  break;

    default : std::cout<<"No value\n";
    }
}


void main()
{
    enumValue storeValue;
    storeValue = fifth;
    enumFunction(storeValue);
}
```

When I change the type of variable "storeValue" to a char the code still gives the same result as before. I am unable to figure out why does the code still work when the parameters being passed have been changed. Here is the code after making the changes to parameters.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef enum
{
    first=0, second=1, third, fourth, fifth, sixth
}enumValue;

void enumFunction(char val)
{
    switch(val)
    {
    case first : std::cout<<"1\n";
                 break;

    case second : std::cout<<"2\n";
                  break;

    case fifth  : std::cout<<"5\n";
                  break;

    default : std::cout<<"No value\n";
    }
}


void main()
{
    char storeValue;
    storeValue = fifth;
    enumFunction(storeValue);
}
```

Is the usage of char instead of an enum appropriate as they both give similar results when executed?? How does the second code work without any syntax errors??

Comment: A `char` is just an integer type.

Comment: ... and enums also are just ints.

Comment: Unscoped enumerators are implicitly convertible to integral types. Also, `void main()` is not valid C++ and `typedef enum { /*...*/ } stuff;` is a C-ism.

Comment: ... and not even valid C.

Comment: @alk `<iostream>` and `std::cout` aren't valid C already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and C++ can implicitly convert between lots of types.  In this case, the integral types `int` and `char` and your `enum`, etc.  It's perfectly permissible to convert your enum value to a char and back again, so long as the values of your enum don't go over 127 (which they do not).

In C and C++, `char` and "8-bit integer" are basically the same thing.  And it isn't an error to convert between bit-widths like int8_t (signed char), int16_t, int32_t, and int64_t.

Comment: Good answer, I want only add that `enum class` was added to prevent the conversion (but is sometimes too hard to use).

Comment: You can't implicitly convert an `int` to an `enum` value, though.

Answer (score 0):

In the `enum`, the elements first, second, third... have there corresponding values 0, 1, 2... which are of type `int`. `char` and `int` can be implicitly converted as long as the `int` value is in the valid range. So when you do

```
storeValue = fifth;
```

Then it is just storing the value of fifth in `storeValue`. And in the function, the `switch` statement is comparing the value.